# Call to undefined function imagewebp()

Tags: php, gd, webp

I am wondering why i get this error. I updated my php from 5.6.22 to 5.6.40 and now i get this error. This was working fine in previous version but suddenly it turns out like this.

Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagewebp()

Also if try `var_dump(function_exists('imagewebp'));` it gives `false` now.

This is my current PHP version

[image: This is my current PHP Verison]

This is the GD Module

[image: GD Extension]

So what has to be done to re-enable it in my server. 
I have a Cent-OS instance in AWS.

Answer (score 2):

The `WBMP Support => enabled` is not enough)
You have to add `--with-vpx-dir=` to your configure line or `--with-webp-dir` for PHP 7.0+

Comment: what is it ? i mean i face same issue but i don't know what to do and where? can you please explain your answer ?

Comment: Hope this help. This is a solution for Azure Linux WebAPP, but it explain what is the usage of `--with-webp-dir`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63708542/7208109

Comment: @CarlosEduardoSalazarMori: This helped me.

Answer (score 1):

For me
PHP: 8

I simply uncommented the extension gd and the function worked

```
extension=gd
```

in my php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

With PHP8.1 and Docker, i simply add this : --with-webp

In DockerFile :
RUN apt-get install libwebp-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg --with-freetype --with-webp && docker-php-ext-install gd