# Enabling gd webp on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, apache, gd

I'm having an issue trying to use Intervention Image to manipulate webp files. The statement causing the error is:

```
Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(250, 250)->save($path);
```

The error I run into is:

```
Unsupported image type. GD/PHP installation does not support WebP format.
```

I have the gd library installed, however it does not support webp.
[image]

I've looked around, and the closest I've found to a solution is here, which suggests adding additional extensions when initially (manually) compiling PHP: [Call to undefined function imagewebp()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57651877/call-to-undefined-function-imagewebp)

I would prefer not to uninstall and manually compile PHP with additional extensions. Is this the only option? Are there any straightforward solutions?